# How to call API url according deployment environment in Angular

Tags: angular

i'm new in angular , i'm workin with services and i'm calling my rest APIin localhost (http://localhost:8097/api/quiz) and all works fine , now i want to deploy my app in another server and this is the rest APIurl (http://192.168.12.36:8097/api/quiz) , so my question is how I can call my rest API dynamically according to the deployment environment, this is the code that I use in my service :

```
export class QuizService {

readonly rootUrl='http://localhost:8097/api/quiz';

  constructor(private httpClient : HttpClient) { }

  getQuestions(){
    return this.httpClient.get(this.rootUrl+'/randomquestions');
  }

}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: If you Check your folder architecture you will find a folder called `environment` then follow what  @Eliran Els said below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up the `environment` and building the same app for different `environment`:

`environment.ts`:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  api: 'http://localhost:8097'
};
```

`environment.prod.ts`:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  api: 'http://192.168.12.36:8097'
};
```

`QuizService.ts`:

```
export class QuizService {

readonly rootUrl= envirment.api + '/api/quiz';

  constructor(private httpClient : HttpClient) { }

  getQuestions(){
    return this.httpClient.get(this.rootUrl+'/randomquestions');
  }

}
```

Offical docs:
https://angular.io/guide/build